# Plotly 3D scatter plot, axis labels, hover and legend edition

Tags: hover, axis-labels, plotly-python, legend-properties

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to make a 3D scatter plot in plotly of the principal components. Something like:

[image]

I have been strugglingin the edition of the properties of the plot. I would like to know:

1. How to edit the hover in order to print Muestra,pc1,pc2,pc3 instead of x,y,z?
2. How to add the legend outside the plot?
3. How to edit the name of the axis?

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pc1": range(11),
        "pc2": range(10, -1, -1),
        'pc3': range(35,46),
        "Muestra": list(string.ascii_uppercase[:11]),
        "color": ["#cf0c0c"] * 6 + ["#0dab51"] * 5,
    },
    index=range(1, 12))

data = go.Scatter3d(x=df.pc1,
                    y=df.pc2,
                    z=df.pc3,
                    mode='markers',
                    marker=dict(size=10, color=df.color, opacity=0.8))

fig = go.Figure(data=[data])

# tight layout
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.show()
```